# PySpark | Join two dataframes in specific column

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem, and after several searches, I have not found the answer to my question.
I am new to pySpark and more generally to dataframes.

I'm looking to "join" / "merge" two dataframes in one column.

I have a profiles df and an orders df, in the profile df I have a column containing arrays of orders id.

I would like to add an "orders" column to my profile dataframe containing the orders associated to the ordersId.

Instinctively I tried that, but in the where context I lose the withColumn context so I can't access my ordersId array

```
profiles = profiles.withColumn('orders', lit(orders.where(array_contains(profiles.ordersId, orders.id)).collect()))
```

If anyone has the answer to my problem, I'm willing to take it.

---

Samples:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType


data = [("aaaa", ['cc', 'dd'])]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("id", StringType(), False), \
    StructField("ordersId", ArrayType(StringType(), False), False), \
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)


data2 = [("cc", "titi"), ("dd", "toto")]

schema2 = StructType([ \
    StructField("id", StringType(), False), \
    StructField("alias", StringType(), False), \
  ])
 
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=schema2)
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(truncate=False)


root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- ordersId: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)

+----+--------+
|id  |ordersId|
+----+--------+
|aaaa|[cc, dd]|
+----+--------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- alias: string (nullable = false)

+---+-----+
|id |alias|
+---+-----+
|cc |titi |
|dd |toto |
+---+-----+
```

And I would like:

```
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------------+
|id  |ordersId|orders                                         |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------------+
|aaaa|[cc, dd]|[{id: cc, alias: titi}, {id: dd, alias: titi}] |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: [examples of join](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples/)

Comment: @samkart Sorry, but I don't understand how I can achieve the desired result with a join

Comment: would be helpful if you share sample records from your dataframes and a sample of the expected output. I don't understand how you want to achieve the desired result

Comment: @samkart, ok I will add some samples and an example of what I would like to output

Comment: @samkart, Can this addition help you?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to `explode` the array and map the IDs. Once mapped, again create array using `collect_list`.

```
profile_sdf. \
    select('id', func.explode('order_id').alias('order_id')). \
    join(order_sdf.selectExpr('id as order_id', 'alias'), 'order_id', 'left'). \
    withColumn('order_struct', func.struct(func.col('order_id').alias('id'), 'alias')). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    agg(func.collect_list('order_struct').alias('orders')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----+------------------------+
# |id  |orders                  |
# +----+------------------------+
# |aaaa|[{cc, titi}, {dd, toto}]|
# +----+------------------------+

# root
#  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- orders: array (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- alias: string (nullable = true)
```